# How to check instance is running in heroku

Tags: php, heroku

I am creating a website on PHP.

I have cloned the source code. using `git clone`

Create an app on Heroku `heroku create` and deployed my code on heroku using command `git push heroku master`.

Now i want to check either my instance is running or not. How to check?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in official [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#deploy-the-app) of heroku

> Ensure that at least one instance of the app is running:
>
> ```
> heroku ps:scale web=1
> ```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked. It _makes_ one dyno run. (It might do other things, too, e.g. actually _reducing_ the number of running dynos.) It doesn't _check_ anything.

Comment: I just posted what official documentation told me. recently i started using heroku.

Comment: Here the documentation uses "ensure" in the sense of making it true if it's not. Essentially, that commands says, "Hey Heroku, please make one web dyno run for my application".

Comment: This does not **check** that the instance is running, it only configures Heroku parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You can run `heroku open`, which will open your app in your default web browser. Of course you can also manually navigate to your app's URL, which should be be `https://<your-app-name>.herokuapp.com`.

You can also run `heroku ps` which will show your app's dynos and their status.

Both of these `heroku` commands accept an `--app` argument in case you want to run them from outside of your project directory or have multiple apps configured.